# Dynamical systems with random parameters

Tags: dynamical-systems, random

I am interested in knowing more about dynamical systems with random parameters of this type:

$$ \partial_t u(t,\omega) = F(u(t,\omega),Z(\omega))$$.

The simplest way to understand what I mean is to start from a deterministic Cauchy problem in $\mathbb{R}^n$, with parameter $Z \in \mathbb{R}$:

$$\dot u(t) = F(u(t),Z), \qquad u(0) = u_0$$

where $F \colon \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$. Now, I want to consider the case in which $Z$ is a random variable, with probability density $\rho_Z$. This leads to the Cauchy problem

$$ \partial_t u(t,\omega) = F(u(t,\omega),Z(\omega)), \qquad u(0,\omega) = u_0$$

Hence the evolution equation is deterministic, but $u(t)$ is a random variable. This setup, at first, seems different from the usual SDE evolution equation. I would like to know if you have any references where I can learn about that. In particular, I would like to learn how to derive an evolution equation for the law of $u(t)$ (similar to what one would get with a Fokker-Planck equation for SDEs).

Comment: It is not clear where you see the interesting point in this. The random point $ω$ and thus the random variable $Z(ω)$ is chosen once and is then valid for all times, the usual laws for the parameter dependence of ODE apply.

Comment: Of course, each sample is a trajectory of an ODE. Uncertainty in the parameter Z (expressed via $\rho_Z$) is propagated forward by the model. One typically wants to find statistics of certain quantities of interests (functions of $u(t)$) when one assigned a distribution function $\rho_Z$. It's not a curiosity: the whole field of forward uncertainty quantification does that

Comment: Arnold's book "Random Dynamical Systems" might be useful. The starting point is to package all the nonautonomous variables into a "base dynamics" and encode the parameter dependency as a skew-product over the base dynamics.

Comment: Thanks. I do not quite get what you mean by nonautonomous variables, given that Z is not time dependent. Could you elaborate a bit?